# Is it possible to grant shared access to a calender but not mailfolders?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

At work we have a shared e-mail account for our team. As of now, only the boss, me (2nd in command) and the secretary have full access to it. We would like to have the rest of the team (about 30 employees) to have access to the calender but not beeing able to read any e-mails in any folders of the account.

Is this possible to achieve on Outlook 2010? If so, is it possible to set read only-rights on the calender for the employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the folder permission in Outlook 2010. Although you have not specified, I'm supposing that you're using **Exchange**. In Outlook there are two types of sharing available that you can set. First you can share as **Folder Permissions** and then you can share as **Delegates**.

Steps to follow: 
1. Open **Outlook** and then find the **Folder List**. In Outlook 2010, Folder List is the default view.

2. From the menu select **Properties** and click on the **Permissions** tab. If **Permission** tab is not present, then you probably had set **Personal Folders** as your default delivery location. Just set the default delivery location to your **Exchange Server Mailbox** in this case.
3. Click on **Add** and select the people you want to grant permission. After each selection click **Add** and when you're done please click **OK**.
4. Now you need to select which permission you want to grant them. If you only want to give them the ability to view items in this particular folder then assign the role of **Reviewer**. Here is the list of roles:

**Owner**: Allows full rights to the mailbox, including assigning permissions; you should not assign this role to anyone

Publishing Editor: Create, read, edit, and delete all items; create subfolders

**Editor**: Create, read, edit, and delete all items

**Publishing Author**: Create and read items; create subfolders; edit and delete items they've created

**Author**: Create and read items; edit and delete items they've created

**Nonediting Author**: Create and read items; delete items they've created

**Reviewer**: Read items

**Contributor**: Create items

**None**: Gives no permissions for the selected accounts on the specified folder

Now the people you have granted permission to, needs to set up their Outlook to view your folders.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You can specify required permissions for Calendar folder in its Properties -> Permissions.

To share calendar only: right-click the Calendar folder, select Share -> Share Calendar. After that specify all required employees in the "To" field and click Send.